# How to define_method with a do and end

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am writing a program that utilizes `define_method`, but I don't understand how I could define a method like this one:

```
def mymethod(variable) do
    puts variable
    puts yield
end
```

Which can be called by:

```
mymethod("hi") do
    # this is yield
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `yield`. You need to receive it as a proc object.

```
define_method(:mymethod) do |variable, &block|
  puts variable
  puts block.call
end

mymethod("foo"){"bar"}
# foo
# bar

mymethod("foo") do "bar" end
# foo
# bar
```

Comment: @thesecretmaster Because `yield` will be interpreted with lexical scope.

Comment: Also that method couldn't be called like `my_method("foo") do; "bar"; end`

Comment: Oh... I just realized, I had a typo when I tested... Oops sorry. Great answer!

Answer (score -2):

```
define_method :my_method do |str, &block|
  # Do something here
  yield  # or block.call
  # Do something here
end
```